# what does "recirculated" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> The construction of a new nuclear plant at Hinkley Point was put in
>   doubt, then given the go-ahead; a new runway at Heathrow airport was
>   all but agreed on, then deferred until a parliamentary vote next year.
>   “Just-about-managing” households were the prime minister’s lodestar
>   for a week or so, then dropped. So were suggestions that Britain would
>   seek a transitional deal with the EU after Brexit—until they were
>   **recirculated** a few weeks later when Mrs May apparently changed her mind once again

Does it mean "to circulate again"?

http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21713837-after-six-months-what-new-prime-minister-stands-still-unclearperhaps-even

Comment: Most English dictionaries include example sentences in which a given word is used. Can you tell us which of these dictionaries you have consulted?

Comment: @P.E.Dant http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recirculated I searched for "recirculated" but somehow I got "circulate"

Comment: You have to read the _entire_ entry; for instance, the section entitled _**Examples from the Web for recirculated**_ contains usages similar to yours.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I read it and my guess is that it means the suggestions became known by many people. is that right?

Comment: No, that's not what it means. The examples are there to demonstrate the ways and contexts in which the word is used in English. I'm sure there are similar dictionaries, with similar examples, in your native language. English dictionaries are exactly the same. Read and understand the examples, and you will better understand the ways in which English speakers use a given word.

Comment: jack - I'm guessing you've not yet read [this meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) – particularly the part that says, "Show your research." In the future, if you include details about what you've already discovered when you tried to answer this question on your own, you'll find folks here will pester you less with quesitons about dictionary lookups and Google searches, and instead focus on answering your question, because we'll have all the details we need to do so.

Comment: Even if the OP had consulted a decent dictionary, the figurative meaning might have remained opaque. So I'm offering an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added additional context to the excerpt to explain the sentence that begins "**So** were", which means "*In the same way* were ..." or "So too were".

The nuclear plant was *put in doubt then given the go-ahead*.

The new runway was *all but agreed on, then deferred*.

An initiative dubbed "Just-about-managing* was the *lodestar for a week then dropped*.

The sentence that begins "So were" follows directly upon the word **dropped**, and thus "So were" means "Also dropped were".

When a sentence begins with **So** where the conjunction means "in the same way, in similar manner" (and not "for that reason"), there is subject-verb inversion, and thus the subject of the sentence is **suggestions**.  So too were suggestions dropped. Which suggestions?  Suggestions *that Britain would seek a transitional deal with the EU after Brexit*.

The author is using the word **recirculated** (loosely) to refer to that pattern of advancing  initiatives and then backing away from them, and reinvigorating  moribund initiatives.

Comment: So it could be said that the suggestions were reinvigorated after abandoned after all?

Comment: Yes, the suggestions to strike a deal with the EU, which had been dropped, were then advanced once again.